# Setting Username/Password programmatically at data source (multiple DSs, Spring, Hibernate)

Tags: spring, hibernate, datasource, credentials, sessionfactory

I'm working on a multi-datasource web portal, using Struts2, Spring and Hibernate. I have a problem with setting the user credentials, which are not available on application startup, but on user login, to one of my data sources. It works for the first portal user, but fails for every following user.

For each data source, a session factory is created, which gets the underlying datasource set via a spring configuration.

Three of my four data sources get their database login credentials set via configuration, **but one must use the credentials of the portal user**. Note, that my beans are in session scope.

Here is my data source configuration:

```
<!-- data source with credentials from configuration -->
<bean id="dataSource1" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" scope="session">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<!-- data source that authenticates with user credentials from login. -->
<bean id="dataSource2" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" scope="session">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${ds2.jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${ds2.jdbc.url}" />
</bean>
```

Here is my session factory configuration:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory1" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean" scope="session">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource1" />
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            ...
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>hibernate/AnotherDTO.hbm.xml</value>
            ...
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory2" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean" scope="session">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource2" />
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            ...
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>hibernate/MyDTO.hbm.xml</value>
            ...
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The portal user's username and password are available only after a successful login to the portal, so they must be set to one of the data sources (dataSource2) programmatically.

I accomplished this by letting Spring insert the data source into my Login Action (Struts2) and then use the provided setter methods to set username and password at the data source after every login.

```
@Qualifier("dataSource2")
private DriverManagerDataSource dataSource2;

private void postAuthenticate() {

        dataSource2.setUsername(user);
        dataSource2.setPassword(password);

}
```

My DAOs get the session factory inserted in the constructor, and pass it on to the HibernateDaoSupport (yes, I work with HibernateTemplate, please no discussion about that at his point ;-) ):

```
public class MyDAO extends HibernateDaoSupport {
    @Autowired
    public MyDAO(@Qualifier("sessionFactory2") SessionFactory pSessionFactory) {
        setSessionFactory(pSessionFactory);
    }
    ...
}
```

**Now, this works fine for the first user that uses the portal.** On the portal's start page a list of items from a DAO using the dataSource2 are displayed. **However, every following user logging in to the portal gets no results from my dataSource2.** No exception is raised, no log messages occur, because there is a valid connection to the db, just with someone else's credentials (and thus returning no suitable results for the second user).

My assumption is, that Hibernate or Spring somehow do not discard the old connection from the session factory of the previous user and keep using it, or ignore the new credentials I set at the new data source.

Can anyone provide some insight or helpful tips (or a solution!) to my problem? I wonder if it is really that hard to use a data source with user credentials that are not available on application startup, but on user login and that there is no easy and generic approach available (I did not find a suitable solution anywhere on the web).

Thank you very much.

Comment: Bad, bad thing. I just found out that my DAOs that use the user-credential session factory are falsly NOT in session scope! This leads to the DAO being treated as a singelton. I wonder why I haven't seen this earlier?

Comment: However, any other great solutions on how to build a data source that uses user credentials that are available after login (and not on application startup) that differs from mine? Any best practices?